Help with a proof that a rational function takes infinite distinct values when it runs through the algebraic closure of a field.
I'm studying Lawrence C. Washington's "Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography" and I need a little help with the proof of Proposition 2.21.
The proposition says that a separable endomorphism of an elliptic curve $\alpha \neq 0$ satisfies $\deg \alpha = \# \ker \alpha$, and a not separable one satisfies $\deg \alpha > \# \ker \alpha$.
(By endomorphism we mean a group endomorphism of the group $E(\overline K)$, where $E(\overline K)$ is the graph of an elliptic curve over the algebraic closure of some field $K$, such that $\alpha(x, y) = (R_1(x, y), R_2(x, y))$ where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rational functions in $\overline K(x, y)$. It focuses on elliptic curves given by a Weierstrass equation $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ and using this expression for $y^2$ and the symmetry from reflecting along the OX axis concludes that then $\alpha(x, y) = (r_1(x), y \, r_2(x))$ for some $r_1(x), r_2(x) \in \overline K(x)$. An endomorphism is said to be separable if $r_1'(x) \neq 0$.)
In the first part of the proof (for separable $\alpha$) it uses the fact that "$r_1(x)$ is easily seen to take on infinitely many distinct values as $x$ runs through $\overline K$. I was indeed easily able to prove this fact using that $\overline K$ is infinite, and that each element in $\overline K$ has a finite amount of inverse images under $r_1(x) = p(x)/q(x)$ because $p(x)/q(x) = a \iff p(x) - aq(x) = 0$, and this polynomial cannot be the zero polynomial because then $r_1(x) = a \implies r_1' = 0$, but since $\alpha$ is separable this cannot be. Therefore, putting the two facts together, if $r_1(\overline K)$ were finite, $\overline K$ would be finite too but that isn't true.
For the second part of the proof ($\alpha$ not separable), it claims that this statement about $r_1(\overline K)$ being infinite still holds. However, I can no longer prove that, if $\alpha$ isn't separable, $r_1$ cannot be constant. I've worked out that if $r_1(x) = x_1$ were constant, then $y \, r_2(x) = \pm y_1$ (where $y_1^2 = x_1^3 + Ax_1 + B$) $\implies r_2(x) = \pm \, y_1/\sqrt{x^3+Ax+B}$ (we're working in an algebraically closed field so we can take the square root, and $y$ has that square-root expression because $(x, y)$ is a point on the elliptic curve), and I guess what I'm missing is to prove that such an expression cannot coincide with a rational function.
